# Meaning of "to be" and a verb in the past participle form in context

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/c7KX5IZ1sVc). It is right at the beginning. Here is the context.

> Today we are talking about loneliness; **not to be confused** with introversion or social anxiety.

What I can understand from the context is that it either means *don't* *confuse it with* or *you should not confuse with*, I am not sure though. And What baffles me the most is the grammar of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89769/why-use-to-be-in-phrases-like-not-to-be-confused-with-instead-of-not-to-con

Comment: "To be" followed by a past participle is almost always the passive voice, and this is no exception. You are correct that it means "you should not confuse loneliness with introversion," but the "you" is eliminated by the use of the passive voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not to be confused with" is a common English idiom. It has several variants, some of which are:

> 'should not be confused with'
>
> 'as distinct from'
>
> 'which is quite different from'
>
> 'unlike'

All of these expressions highlight the fact that a particular word, concept or idea that appears before the expression, should not be confused with a similar word, concept or idea that appears after the expression. It is usually used when someone wants to be sure that  the people who are reading, or hearing, his/her words do not confuse them with words, or concepts, or ideas that appear to be similar or closely related. e.g.

> Patriotism, not be confused with nationalism, can be an important binding force within a country.
>
> In order to be a good communicator you need to learn that listening is quite different from hearing.
>
> Tin is an element, unlike bronze which is an alloy or compound.
>
> Education, as distinct from schooling, is a lifelong endeavour.